# Upgrading windows 2012 R2 to Windows 2016 Server with Sharepoint 2016 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, upgrade, windows

Wanted to know if a windows 2012 R2 machine with SharePoint 2016 installed can be upgraded to windows 2016 server?

SharePoint app is installed on 1 machine and sql server is on a separate machine.

Both machines would be upgraded to Windows 2016 server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, in place upgrade of windows server is not supported for SharePoint servers.You'd better rebuild the SharePoint Farm.

Here is a similar issue for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f8a31b7-3a17-40ee-904c-f8fd5c01fd2a/sharepoint-2016-server-os-upgrade-from-windows-server-2012-r2-datacenter-to-windows-server-2016?forum=SP2016

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If my answer helps you, you could accept it: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers